# Hyperref + Javascript with Selected Checkbox Counted

Tags: hyperref

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{form}

\CheckBox[name=test]{}
\CheckBox[name=test]{}

\TextField[readonly=true,name=sum,width=45pt,
calculate = {
this.getField('sum').value = this.getField("test").value;
}
]{~}

\end{form}

\end{document}
```

How can I produce the number of selected `test` checkboxes in the `sum` field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the checkboxes different names if you want to be able to check them individually. And the name of the environment is `Form` not `form`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\CheckBox[name=test1]{}
\CheckBox[name=test2]{}

\bigskip
\TextField[readonly=true,name=sum,width=45pt,
calculate = {
this.getField('sum').value = 
         (this.getField("test1").value=="Yes") + 
         (this.getField("test2").value=="Yes") ;
}
]{~}

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]